# When it is useful to use the strings?

Tags: linux

When it is useful to use command `strings` ?

I dot' see any advantage of this command, where is it using ? For what ?

I wrote a little program, that u need to guess a password and thats all of my ideas where this command is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings is used to Search and display the printable strings in a binary file.

Comment: Ok I know that, but when you want to use? When is nessesery to use strings ?